# Azure Event grid - Delayed Execution

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I am working on a design where I need to move files from one Storage account to another storage account. And after let's say a week, delete those files.

One file is going to successfully move I can either either send a message to `Event Hub` or Write a record into `SQL DB`

For Deletion of files I have two approach.

I have two approach:

**Polling**

1. Poll daily for SQL DB entry and then check the `last modified timestamp` and delete it.
2. Update the SQL DB entry for the file and reflect that file is deleted.

**Event Based**

1. Send a message to  event grid as soon as the file is deleted.

However, I am not able to figure out how to wait for 1 week before I delete a file. If I had to delete file immediately I can do upon receiving message.

Comment: have a look at the storage lifecycle management features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blob-storage-lifecycle-management-now-generally-available/

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Service Bus queues with schedule feature? Service Bus queues/topics may be a better fit for delayed processing requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sequencing#scheduled-messages

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This seems like a really good option. let me explore it a bit.